# How to add child entity without parent in OneToOne bidirectional relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities: Group and User.
Both are in OneToOne relationship, User is parent and Group is a child.

Problem is that I have an error when I save the group entity to the database:
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.robert.app.ws.io.entity.GroupEntity.user]

Group entity:

```
    public class GroupEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
private List<ChildEntity> children;

//FK z tablicy users
@OneToOne
@MapsId
UserEntity user;

//getters and setters
```

User entity:

```
    public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8748598732973872010L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String userId;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
private String firstName;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
private String lastName;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 15)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
private String pesel;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private AccountType accountType;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
private String address;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;

private String encryptedPassword;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", 
orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ChildEntity> children = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private GroupEntity group;
```

GroupServiceImlp class:

```
    @Override
    public GroupDto createGroup(GroupDto group) {

    GroupEntity groupEntity = new GroupEntity();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(group, groupEntity);

    GroupEntity storedGroup = groupRepository.save(groupEntity);

    GroupDto returnValue = new GroupDto();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(storedGroup, returnValue);

    return returnValue;
}
```

I want to create the group and assign the user to this group later (would like to do it in android application). I have a button where I just add new group to database. In another view I would like to match particular group which is already created, with the user.

I am sure I do not understand something related to relationships in JPA, but I am new in Spring, so thats why I am looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@MapsId` in `GroupEntity`

By default, the entities are mapped by IDs. Your `GroupEntity` should look like that.

```
public class GroupEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private List<ChildEntity> children;

    //FK z tablicy users
    @OneToOne
    UserEntity user;

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: It helped! I had to remove the tables to make it work, but its working :)
In this case when I would like to match group with the user - how should I do it ?
Are you able to show me an example if my relation would be unidirectional and bidirectional ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Your relation is a bidirectional relation. The `user` refers the `group` and the `group` refers the `user`. If you want an unidirectional relation - remove one of the references.